# VSTO C# Word crashes after pasting bitmap to a footer

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

Writing an add-in.
Trying to place an image in the footer of a Word document from an .resx file.
Since the `InlineShapes.addPicture` requires a path to a file, figured out I could use the clipboard instead to insert the picture (only temporarily), but Word keeps on crushing when Paste() is used.
it exits with code 0 (0x0).

Here is the code:

```
private void placeFooterNavigationOnce()
{
    Word.Range footerRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Sections[1].Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    Clipboard.SetImage(Resource1.Brackets);
    footerRange.Select();
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Paste();
}
```

Edit- Additional info:

`inlineShapes.addPicture` Does the same task without any errors.

Pasting the image in the body of the document works as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Good question, your code looks fine! To debug this issue further, I would suggest to try if it also happens if do the last step (paste) (1) manually (using the keyboard) and/or (2) with VBA. If it happens with VBA as well, you might be able to create a VBA [mcve], which would greatly increase the chances of other people being able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the Select and Selection lines and use instead: `footerRange.Paste();` If that also crashes, comment out everything after `Clipboard.SetImage` so that the resource is on the Clipboard. Go to the Word document *as a user* and look in the Home/Clipboard/Paste/Paste Special dialog box. What file types are listed there? Are you able to choose any and have Word paste successfully? Are you sure the resource is being placed on the Clipboard as a bitmap? You may need to set the data type?

Comment: This sounds familiar to a problem I had in a VB.Net solution and trying to get an Resource image onto the clipboard. I was probably doing something wrong, but couldn't figure it out. My solution was to get the object from Resources and set an Image variable, which I could then save to a temp directory. From there it was InlineShapes.Add into the document and Kill the temp file.

Comment: @RichMichaels you have saved the day! it's a great alternative solution for this task. Using clipboard is weird anyway.

Comment: @Heinzi, Thanks! I've done it manually, it works well. wanted to see if it was something superficial, because I'm new to .NET. next time I'll include more background info and an example.

Comment: @CindyMeister `footerRange.Paste();` still crashes. It works fine when pasting in the body of the doc.

Comment: Then I'd next try collapsing the Range before pasting: footerRange.Collapse(1); footerRange.Paste(); - you could also try with Collapse(0); - just if you're curious whether it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MikeK, here is what I do in a VB.NET solution to get around trying to figure out why a Clipboard Copy/Paste of the bitmap wouldn't work for me. I'm sure you can adapt it to a C# solution.

```
            Dim img as Image, fName as String
            fName = "rClock32"
            img = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(fName)
            img.Save(ThisAddIn.LGPUserTempDir & fName & ".png")
            wApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(ThisAddIn.LGPUserTempDir & fName & ".png")
            Kill(ThisAddIn.LGPUserTempDir & fName)
            img = Nothing
```